# derivative of determinant of second order tensor with respect to determinant?

Tags: derivatives, tensors

As stated in the comments, I will specify my problem in more detail:

$\boldsymbol A$ is a symmetric Tensor tensor of 2nd order

Third invariant of $\boldsymbol A$:

$III_{\boldsymbol A} = \det \boldsymbol A \\
\frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A} }{\partial \boldsymbol A} = \det \boldsymbol A \ \boldsymbol A^{-1}
$

There is a scalar function $E$ dependent on the third invariant of $\boldsymbol A$:

$E = E(III_{\boldsymbol A})$

A symmetric 2nd order stress tensor is then defined as:

$\boldsymbol S = \frac{\partial E}{\partial \boldsymbol A} 
= \frac{\partial E}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A} } \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A}$

What I want to compute is a 4th order tangent as follows:

$\boldsymbol L = \frac{\partial \boldsymbol S}{\partial \boldsymbol A} = \frac{\partial \boldsymbol S}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}} \otimes \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} \\ = \frac{\partial}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}} \left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A} } \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol C}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} \right)  \otimes \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} \\ = \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}} \left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}} \right) \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} +  \frac{\partial E}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A} } \frac{\partial}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}} \left(  \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} \right) \right] \otimes \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A}$
\

The last summand in the square brackets is given by:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}} \left(  \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} \right) = \frac{\partial \det \boldsymbol A \ \boldsymbol A^{-1} }{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}} = \frac{\partial \det \boldsymbol A \ \boldsymbol A^{-1} }{\partial \det \boldsymbol A}$

And this is the expression which we talked about in the comments. I do not know at which point I made a mistake to come up with that expression.

Comment: Your expressions, as they stand, don't make sense to me. the determinant function has a domain consisting of space of matrices, and its codomain is $\mathbb{R}$. When you want to differentiate this expression you need to fix an element of the domain, in the case, a matrix $A$, perturb it by another matrix and take a difference quotient ultimately taking the limit (be it a directional derivative or the Jacobian).  You can't perturb $A$ by $det(A)$ since $det(A)$ lives in $\mathbb{R}$ and not in space of matrices.

Comment: @Leonid I edited my question a little bit. The expression $\frac{\partial \mathrm{det} (\boldsymbol A)}{\partial \mathrm{det} (\boldsymbol A)}$ is the result after applying product rule to the original expression. According to you, I am not even sure if applying the product rule like I did is a valid operation.

Comment: Your new function $A \to det(A)A^{-1}$ is a map from the space of invertible matrices to the spaces of matrices, so your expression still doesn't make sense: the domain of your new function is still a matrix space and what you did doesn't make things any better.

Comment: This makes sense. I think I have to specify my problem statement in more detail. Would you help me if I edit my question again and post the original problem including all the transformations I did?

Comment: Do whatever you feel is necessary to get your point across. If I have something to add, I'll add it.

Comment: I edited my question again such that you can see how I derived the above expression.

Comment: @Leonid In case you already had time to look at my question again, can you add something to it or is it too specific?